# Getting low level information from usb driver

Tags: usb

I have a goal to check event from connecting a 5V pin and D+ pin of usb port on raspberry. Here is dmesg output of this event:

```
[24242.563906] usb 3-6: USB disconnect, device number 3
[24242.563910] usb 3-6.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[24248.106279] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[24248.218469] usb 3-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[24248.434651] usb 3-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[24248.650752] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[24248.762919] usb 3-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[24248.979099] usb 3-6: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[24249.195208] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[24249.195342] usb 3-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[24249.399529] usb 3-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[24249.603537] usb 3-6: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[24249.715631] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[24249.715763] usb 3-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[24249.919989] usb 3-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[24250.123970] usb 3-6: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[24250.124031] usb usb3-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Is there any other option to check this event than parsing /var/log/messages?